# Wavesurfer: update wave color from point A to point B

Tags: wavesurfer.js

Is it any way, how can I update the wavecolor from point A to point B only? I want to implement the hover effect, when mouse enter on my Waveform and I want to change the color from waveform start to current cursor point. Sorry, cannot provide any code, cause I not even understand, how to start